# HTML combobox shows incorrect item when set programmatically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Before I begin, I can categorically state that I am not a web developer. I am currently attempting to fix the following bug in our small web app (used for configuring an embedded device), given that the web-fluent developers who wrote it are no longer around to ask for pointers. I'll try and explain as best I can what's going on.

This particular web page is set up to allow the user to configure and monitor values on an audio processing device. When the user changes a value on the page, the page sends an RPC request to the device to set the value there. When a value on the device is changed via some other means (eg. manually via the input screen), a JSON notification is sent to the web page and the relevant control is updated via JavaScript. The web page uses Bootstrap for the UI, and Knockout for ensuring that the relevant controls are updated whenever values (which we refer to as "parameters" on the device) are changed.

The issue I'm having is that comboboxes (ie. controls constructed via `<select>` and `<option>` tags in HTML) will sometimes not display the appropriate values when they are changed through JavaScript. If the user selects an item in the combobox, and the corresponding value is later changed on the device (and propagated back to the web page via JavaScript), the combobox will no longer be able to display the item that the user originally selected - instead, it will display the first item.

For example, with a combobox containing items A, B, C, D and E:

User selects: D.

When value is sent from device to web page:

- Item A displays as A
- Item B displays as B
- Item C displays as C
- Item D displays as A
- Item E displays as E

This does not happen if the user hasn't ever interacted with the combobox - in this case, whatever value the device notifies the page with will be displayed correctly.

I don't have enough experience to know how all the gory details work behind the scenes, but I have investigated far enough to know the following:

- When changing the value via JavaScript, the combobox responds to the Knockout observable changing. I'm not 100% sure how this all gets hooked up, but within the `data-bind` attribute that Knockout requires on the combobox, `foreach`is set to `$data.widgetData.options`, amongst other things. I don't know whether this is relevant or not.
- The value set on the Knockout observable that corresponds to the combobox exactly matches the `value` attribute for the desired combobox option in all cases. I confirmed this by creating another manual subscription to the Knockout observable and logging out the value when it changed.
- When the Knockout observable value is changed, the `selected` attribute is set on the correct combobox option, and is removed from whatever option was previously selected. This happens correctly in both cases (when the combobox displays the correct current value, and when it does not). This also occurs correctly when the user selects an item through the UI, leading me to believe it's not the cause of the issue.

In short: once the user has selected an item at least once, and further changes to the combobox are made programmatically, all the HTML attibute-related modifications *appear* to work exactly the same as before - except the combobox doesn't display the correct contents for the one item that the user selected.

When the combobox is present on the page, the HTML ends up looking something like this:

```html
<select
  class="form-control"
  data-bind="
    attr: { 
      'data-panelid': panelData.__hierarchyId,
      'data-paramtrigger': widgetData.paramTrigger,
      'data-widgetref': widgetData.ref,
      'data-menuRef': widgetData.menuRef,
      'data-widgetNotifyType': widgetData.notifyType
    },
    disable: ($data.widgetData.disabled ? $data.widgetData.disabled : false), 
    foreach: $data.widgetData.options
  "
  data-panelid="system-1-mpx-1"
  data-widgetref="dspx.enum.8"
>
  <option data-bind="
    attr: {
      'data-paramtrigger': $parents[0].widgetData.paramTrigger,
      'value': $data.name,
      'selected': ($root.remoteParameterObservables[$parents[0].widgetData.ref]() == $data.name ? 'selected' : null),
      'data-notifyType': $parents[0].widgetData.notifyType
    },
    text: ($data.webName ? webName : ($data.displayName ? displayName : name))
  "
  value="none">none</option>
  <!-- ... etc ... -->
</select>
```

(Whitespace/newlines added for readability.)

Again, I'm not 100% sure how much of this is specific to our setup and how much is part of what Knockout requires.

Is there any reason why a combobox might behave this way? It could well be that there's something in our Javascript code that's causing the issue, but since I'm not familiar with these kinds of web technologies I wanted to first see whether the cause might be something more obvious.

**EDIT**

For context, this is a trimmed-down version of the Javascript that handles notifications of value changes from the device:

```
// Called when a notification is received from the device.
var onNotify = function(data)
{
    // If we have a KO observable for the parameter on the device with this name
    // (eg. "system.param.1"):
    if (remoteViewModel.remoteParameterObservables.hasOwnProperty(data.name))
    {
        try
        {
            // Set the value of the observable.
            remoteViewModel.remoteParameterObservables[data.name](data.value);
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            console.debug('Param `' + param + '` on remoteViewModel.remoteParameterObservables is not a knockout observable');
        }
    }
}

// ...

// Elsewhere, when creating KO observables, I inserted this for debugging purposes.
// This function always prints out the value I expect, whenever the observable is changed.
if ( parameterName === "param.im.testing.with" )
{
    observableForThisParam.subscribe(function(newValue)
    {
        console.log("Parameter was updated with a new value:", newValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: This might not necessarily be an answer to your question, but it's very strange to use a foreach data-binding on the select and a value/selected bnding on the option.
Normally, you'd use the built-in [options-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) or [selectedOptions-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html).
It seems a lot of logic was written into the template, while the recommended approach is to keep your logic within the ViewModel so it's easier to add automated tests.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to update the value programmatically? Generally, you should be updating the variable, not the widget value.

Comment: This looks like an ugly hack to get a bootstrap "selectpicker" widget working without a proper Knockout binding. Custom bindings for Bootstrap selectpickers have been written, my first instinct would be to employ one of those and replace this hacky code.

Comment: It would not at all surprise me if the Knockout code were hacky - I'll try to patch it up with some of these recommendations. I'll also add a brief overview of the update code, just in case it's helpful.

Comment: Even with your additions it's still impossible to track down what could cause the problem you see. I can only guess at the complex mechanics that drive this. Without a runnable example that includes the relevant code and reproduces the error we won't be able to help, I'm afraid.

Comment: To be honest, I think the prevailing sentiment is "The problem emerges from code over-complication". I'm perfectly happy to agree with this, since I'm having trouble understanding how it all works myself. I suspect if I refactor things and bring the code quality up, the issue might resolve itself.

Comment: I can confirm that using the proper "options" binding seems to have solved the issue. Not sure why it was originally hooked up the way it was.

Comment: I suspect because the bootstrap select widget is painted on top of/instead of the physical HTML `<select>`, but the knockout options binding does not know anything about bootstrap, so it won't inform it of any updates it makes, while bootstrap, not knowing anything about knockout, does not assume anything would silently make changes to the underlying select. This can cause the UI and the viewmodel to become out of sync. This situation is best resolved by introducing knockout and bootstrap to each other via a custom binding. Here is one that looks good: https://codepen.io/quickstep25/pen/gbvREN